# Calculating total in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have my form done but I am trying to create a handling form which calculates the total plus shipping of $5 and 8% tax rate and displays it. 
Need a handling form for my following PHP code. The handling form should calculate total price, 8%tax, $5 shipping fee. It should say thank you for ordering (name entered in form) on (date entered in form)

Need a handling form for my following PHP code. The handling form should calculate total price, 8%tax, $5 shipping fee. It should say thank you for ordering (name entered in form) on (date entered in form)

```
<html 
<head>
</head>
<body>


<link rel= "stylesheet" href= "order.css">
<form action="complete.php" method="post">
<form name="order">
<fieldset><legend>Complete Order:</legend>
<h1> Choose Design </h1>
<p><label>Your Name: <input type="text" name="name"></label>
<label>Address: <input type="text" name="address"></label>
    <label>Credit Card #: <input type="text" name="creditcard"></label>
    <label>Date: <input type="date" id="datepicker" name='date' size='9' value="" > </label>


<br><label> Design Types: <img src="1.jpg"><input type="checkbox" name="1"></label> $1.00 
<label><img src="2.jpg"><input type="checkbox" name="2"> </label>$1.00
<label><img src="3.jpg"><input type="checkbox" name="3"> </label>$1.00

<br></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Order"> 
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far. StackOverflow isn't a freelance service.

Comment: why there are 2 form tags, <form action="complete.php" method="post">
<form name="order"> ??

Answer (score 1):

This is the handler, but before I start on the answer. I just wish to make it clear that Stack Overflow is a Q&A environment and not a place for someone to do your work. That being said, I have answered this question...

Place this code at the top of the HTML page that I will post (I have made some amendments).
Note the `$date` variable uses the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to ensure a date will get posted to the database. I have formatted the date in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format which is the format of MySQL databases (I'm not sure about the format the others use, but I imagine it is the same).

```php
<?php
// only run if form is posted
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    // set POST to variables (easy to type variable name)
    $name       = $_POST["name"];
    $address    = $_POST["address"];
    $creditcard = $_POST["creditcard"];
    $date       = $_POST["date"] == "" ? date("Y-m-d") : $_POST["date"];
    $design     = $_POST["designType"];

    $total = $design; // add the cost of design
    $total += $total * 1.08; // work out tax
    $total += 5; // the shipping fee
}
?>
```

I have made a few changes to the form that you posted. Here they are:

- I indented the tags (it's a personal preference but I think it makes it look neater)
- Added `</fieldset>` to the end of the form. This ensures it passes [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) which requires closing of tags
- I changed the `checkboxes` to `radio` types. This was an assumption based on how I thought you form was supposed to be (I wasn't sure where total was coming from otherwise; so I assumed the "Design type" was the price)
- I reformatted the `<label>` and `<input>` so that they weren't nested (with the exception of radio elements, but that is so you can click the label to select the radio)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="order.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <?php if (isset($_POST["submit"])) { ?><div id="message">Thank you, <?php echo $name; ?> for ordering on <?php echo $date; ?>. The total was <?php echo "$" . number_format($total, 2); ?>  </div><?php } ?>
    <form name="order" action="complete.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Complete Order:</legend>

            <h1>Choose Design</h1>

            <label>Your Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" />
            <label>Address:</label><input type="text" name="address" />
            <label>Credit Card #:</label><input type="text" name="creditcard" />
            <label>Date:</label><input type="date" id="datepicker" name='date' size='9' value="" />

            <br />

            <label>Design Types:</label>
            <label><img src="1.jpg" alt="$1.00" /><input type="radio" name="designType" value="1" />$1.00</label>
            <label><img src="2.jpg" alt="$2.00" /><input type="radio" name="designType" value="2" />$2.00</label>
            <label><img src="3.jpg" alt="$3.00" /><input type="radio" name="designType" value="3" />$3.00</label>

            <br />

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Order" /> 
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

That is all.
Again, let me reinforce the idea that Stack Overflow is not here for this type of "question". Please also provide an attempt at your problem as well.

Comment: Sorry but I forgot to to post what I had worked on PHP. I just posted again but there are still some errors which I am unable to solve with calculation. Can you please try to check it?

Comment: @TechGeek After 6 months, there is still no errors or PHP that you "worked on".